# extract columns from file based on header selected from 2nd file in matlab or R

Tags: r, matlab, indexing, subset

I have one large text table, tab separated. The first row is a header. I then have a second text file that contains a subset of the headers in the first file. I want to extract all the columns of the first file whose header is contained in the list given in the second file. Here an example of the inputs and the desired output:

Data.txt

```
 head0 head1 head2 head3 head4  
 1 25 1364 22 13  
 2 10 215 1 22
```

List.txt

```
head0  
head4
```

Desired Output

```
head0 head4  
1 13  
2 22
```

Comment: Read both datasets with `read.table`, then use `df1[df2[[1]]`  If the second dataset column is `factor`, convert it to `character` `df1[as.character(df2[[1]])]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `base R` methods for this

```
df1[df2[[1]]]
```

#### data

```
#specify the `sep` as well
df1 <- read.table('Data.txt', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- read.table('List.txt', header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `R` is straightforward to do this (given you can easily read the data). It would be something like

```
mydata <- read.table('data_filename.txt', header=T, ...)

# This one looks like header=F in your example...not quite sure how your data is structured
mycolumns <- read.table('columns_filename.txt', header=F, ...)

# x should be the name of the column
final_data <- dplyr::select(mydata, mycolumns$x)
```

Code is not complete but it should be easy to work out the details
It can also be done in base R by subsetting (see other answer).